# Zend Framework: How to subtract amount from database table field?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I want to subtract a amount from a table's field in Zend Framework. I can run it with SQL using following query:

```
UPDATE `Person` SET credit=credit-50 where id=1
```

But how to write above SQL query in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$row = array('credit' => new Zend_Db_Expr('credit - 50'));
$where = "id = 1";
$nRowsAffected = $db->update('Person', $row, $where);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Zend_Db_Expr](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns-expr)

```
  $data = array(
      'credit'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('credit - 50'),
  );
  $n = $db->update('Person', $data, 'id=1');
```